# I've tried to create a numpy matrix of 3-D, but got the error: TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '5'

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-lab

`import numpy as np a = np.matrix([11,25,40], [5,34,98], [32,12,60])`

PS: Also reviewed the similar question asked but the array was not complete there. Please guide what to do here?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSyH8.png)

Comment: did you reread the `np.matrix` docs once you got the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the lists into a main list. the `matrix` constructor accepts a single iterable:

```
a = np.matrix([[11,25,40], [5,34,98], [32,12,60]])
```

output:

```
matrix([[11, 25, 40],
        [ 5, 34, 98],
        [32, 12, 60]])
```

*NB. note that the use of `matrix` is no longer recommended (see [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), you should use **[`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)** instead*

Answer (score -2):

You can the below code:

```py
import numpy as np

np=np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]])
print(np)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).